# Is there a method to update UI of a DefaultMutableTreeTableNode when model of this node is changed?

Tags: java, swing, swingx, treetable, jxtreetable

```
public class MyNode extends DefaultMutableTreeTableNode {
    MyModel model;
    public MyNode(MyModel model){
        this.model= model;
    }
}

public MyTreeTableModel extends DefaultTreeTableModel{
...
}

public MyTreeTable extends JXTreeTable{
....
}
MyNode root = loading(...);
MyTreeTableModel tableModel = new MyTreeTableModel(root);
MyTreeTable myTree = new MyTreeTable(tableModel);
```

I have a node A and `model` of this node is changed, so i only want to update UI of this node.
`myTree.updateUI()` worked well but it is expensive because update all tree.

Is there directly method or better approach ?

Comment: Use the `TreeModel` to build and generate event notifications back to the `JTree`

Comment: Can you more detail ? i found TreeModelListener but still can't use it

Comment: what kind a change? if it is only about view (Color etc.) you can use a renderer. ıf your model object replacing with another one, it is a different situation of course.

Comment: [DefaultTreeModel#nodeChanged](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#nodeChanged(javax.swing.tree.TreeNode))

Comment: `DefaultTreeTableModel`  is different with `DefaultTreeModel`, it doesn't have nodeChanged method, btw i found the `setUserObject` method to workaround for this.